# INSERT INTO with JOINS in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, sql-insert

Hi I try to adapt this [blog post](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/data-vault-link-loads-explained-part-one) to my needs using Oracle to model a Data Vault architecture.

With the following code I try to build a `link` between two `hubs` referencing on the original `source` table "orders".

```
INSERT INTO l_customer_order (customer_id_hk, order_id_hk, load_date, record_source)  
    SELECT DISTINCT h_customers.customer_id_hk, h_orders.orders_id_hk, SYSDATE, 'Customer+Order'
    FROM orders as src
    LEFT OUTER JOIN h_orders
    ON (h_orders.order_id =  src.order_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN h_customers
    ON (h_customers.customer_id = src.customer_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN l_customer_order AS dest
    ON (dest.customer_id_hk = h_customers.customer_id_hk) 
    AND  (dest.order_id_hk = h_orders.order_id_hk)
    WHERE dest.order_id_hk IS NULL;
```

However I receive following error.

```
Error at Command Line : 192 Column : 17
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help or hint much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of INSERT statement.

Comment: Oracle does not support the `as`keyword for table aliases - you must type `orders src`, not `orders as src`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where you have used the `as` keyword. For giving alias to the table you just need to write the name of the alias after table name. `as` should not be used there.

Try the following code: (changes are mentioned inline)

```
INSERT INTO l_customer_order (customer_id_hk, order_id_hk, load_date, record_source)  
    SELECT DISTINCT h_customers.customer_id_hk, h_orders.orders_id_hk, SYSDATE, 'Customer+Order'
    FROM orders src -- removed AS from here
    LEFT OUTER JOIN h_orders
    ON (h_orders.order_id =  src.order_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN h_customers
    ON (h_customers.customer_id = src.customer_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN l_customer_order dest -- removed AS from here
    ON (dest.customer_id_hk = h_customers.customer_id_hk) 
    AND  (dest.order_id_hk = h_orders.order_id_hk)
    WHERE dest.order_id_hk IS NULL;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `as` in your query i.e. instead of

```
FROM orders as src
```

use

```
 FROM orders src
```

Oracle doesn't support the `as` alias, unless it is/will be added in most current versions